# org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm using Spring 4.3.8 and Hibernate 5.2.10 and I'm trying to create table in database and insert records to that but I'm getting Error

Dao Class

```
@Transactional
    public void saveDayBookData(DayBookData dayBook){
        hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().setFlushMode(FlushMode.AUTO);
        hibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(dayBook);
    }
```

For all spring and hibernate configuration

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd">


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1?autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false"></property>
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>
        <property name="password" value="root"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mysessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="entityClasses"></property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="template" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="vendor" class="vendors.VendorDao">
        <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="template"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dayBook" class="accountBooks.DayBookDao">
        <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="template"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Main class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Resource r = new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");
        BeanFactory bean = new XmlBeanFactory(r);

        DayBookDao dayBookDao = (DayBookDao) bean.getBean("dayBook");
        DayBookData dayBook =  new DayBookData();
        dayBook.setAccountType("Bank Account");
        dayBook.setTransType("Receipt");
        dayBook.setOppAccount("Profit-Loss");
        dayBook.setAmount(15000);
        dayBook.setTransDate(new Date());
        dayBookDao.saveDayBookData(dayBook);
    }
```

I'm getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:456)
    at accountBooks.DayBookDao.saveDayBookData(DayBookDao.java:22)
    at accountBooks.TestDayBook.main(TestDayBook.java:28)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is the way you are creating DAO.

Instead add scan to your `applicationContext.xml`

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.your.package.here" />
```

Annotate the DAO classes with `@Repository` to let Spring create Proxy for them.

And remove DAO beans declaring from the xml.

Answer (score 0):

My similar issue got fixed with below 2 approaches.

1. Through manually handling transactions.

   Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
   Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
   UserInfo user = (UserInfo) session.get(UserInfo.class, 1);
   tx.commit();
2. Tell Spring to open and manage transactions for you in your web.xml filters and Ensure to use @Repository @Transactional

   < filter >
           < filter-name >hibernateFilter< /filter-name >
           < filter-class >org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter< /filter-class >
           <  init-param >
               < param-name>sessionFactory
               < param-value>session.factory
           < /init-param >
       < /filter >
       < filter-mapping >
           < filter-name>hibernateFilter< /filter-name >
           < url-pattern>/*< /url-pattern >
       < /filter-mapping >

Sorry for improper formatting.